# how to return a laravel view() with parameters to an ajax response

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I have this issue with returning a view() from laravel to an ajax succcess. I don't know how to pass the view with the parameters and redirect to the url in the route path.

This is my route:

```
Route::get('/dd/{id}/add', 'DDController@add');
```

This is my ajax request:

```
 $('#btn-add').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        const dl_id = $('#select_dl').val();
        const url = `/dd/${dl_id}/add`;

        $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: url,
                success: function (res){
                    //something with redirect?
                }
            });

    })
```

My controller:

```
public function add($id){
        
        $dL = LD::find($id);
        $dD = DD::where('l_d_id', $dl_id)->where('ia', true)->get();

        return view('dD.add', [
            'dL' => $dL,
            'dD' => $dD,
        ])->render();
    }
```

And then my view:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="card mb-4">
    <div class="card-body">

        <form method="post" action="/dd/{{$dL->id}}/values">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            @foreach ($dD as $dd)
                <div class='row mb-2 row-dd'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='dd_id[]' value="">
                    <div class='col'>
                        <label for='value[]'>Value for {{$dd->name}} (Id {{$dd->id_field}})</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="value[]" placeholder="Some value" required max_length='{{$dd->max_length}}'>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id='btn-submit'>Submit</button>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-secondary" id='btn-cancel'>Exit</a>
        </form>
            
    </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

Anyone knows how to render the view() or redirect in json format with the parameteres?
Thank you!

Comment: You want to return the view section in the AJAX, right?

Comment: yes, finally I only put window.location.href = url; in the AJAX success and then redirect to the return from controller.